# Corona SDK: How to make object move forward?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a physics body, and I want it to move forward in the direction that it is facing. I'm only thirteen which I hope explains why I'm so bad at trigonometry. Can anyone tell me how to do this in Corona?

Comment: Check out the last comment [here](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/01/28/help-shooting-bullets), it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm gonna assume you want to push your object with a force. Either way we'll need to get an x and y component of the direction your body is facing. Here's how to get the x and y from the rotation angle:

```
-- body is your physics body
local angle = math.rad(body.rotation)  -- we need angle in radians
local xComp = math.cos(angle)  -- the x component
local yComp = -math.sin(angle)  -- the y component is negative because 
                                --  "up" the screen is negative
```

(note: if this doesn't give the facing direction, you may need to add 90, 180, or 270 degrees to your angle, for example: math.rad(body.rotation+90) )

The above code will give you the x and y components of the [unit vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitVector.html) in the direction of the rotation. You'll probably also need some multiplier to get the magnitude of force you want.

```
local forceMag = 0.5 -- change this value to apply more or less force
-- now apply the force
body:applyLinearImpulse(forceMag*xComp, forceMag*yComp, body.x, body.y)
```

Here's where I got the math: http://www.mathopenref.com/trigprobslantangle.html. Using a unit vector simplifies the math because the hypotenuse is always 1

Answer (score 0):

How about making your own character moving towards an angle before using the confusing physics?

```
angle = math.rad(Insert the angle you want here)
character.x = character.x - math.sin(angle)
character.y = character.y + math.cos(angle)
```

Answer (score -1):

Er. You don't need Trigonometry just to move the object.

Add

```
object:translate(distanceToMoveInXAxis,distanceToMoveInYAxis)
```

Or if you want to perform a transition,

```
transition.to(object,{x=object.x + distanceToMoveInXAxis,y=object.y + distanceToMoveInYAxis})
```

Comment: He needs math to calculate the X,Y movement translation from a facing and speed/movement distance. For instance, if he has an object at 200,56 and it's facing is 30° (the 1 hand on a clock) and we wants to move 62 pixels, what are his arguments to `object:translate`?